# how to integrate hebo html template into yii framework

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-events

[how to integrate hebo html template into yii framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246555/how-to-integrate-hebo-html-tempalte-into-yii-framework)

I am new to using yii framework.I download hebo template from

http://www.webapplicationthemes.com/hebo-responsive-html5-theme/

I can installed template hebo but i don´t work with ie.

Don´t work fluid bootstrap.

Comment: It would be great to see an error message or more information what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 1):

go to views/layouts/main.php and delete html comment " <- Require the header ->" instead you can add it as php comment. This comment appears before  tag and it causes IE doesn´t understand HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Did you convert the theme to work with Yii?

One of the problems with this kind of theme is that it has multiple page types and this is harder to replicate in Yii.  By default, Yii has no concept of page type unless you code this into the controller using layouts ....

At the very simplest level, the conversion could be based on the fullwidth page,, converting the mainContent divs to inject $content.  You would then need to change a layout to use single column ...

I've just completed this for another of their templates and it doesn't take too long - though if any one has a better idea for page types I would be very interested ....